# Cannot access S3 from a task running in AWS Fargate

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-fargate

I've seen many references to similar questions on StackOverflow, but I have implemented all of the suggestions I've come across and am still having difficulties. I have an application running from a Docker image on Fargate, from which I need to access S3. I have provided both a task role and a task execution role, and both are properly assumed by my task. The task role had the following policies attached:

```
AmazonS3FullAccess
AmazonECS_FullAccess
AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
```

Regardless of the task role seemingly being correctly implemented, I receive the following error when I try to pull from S3 from the application:

```
CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1
```

It's my understanding that Fargate should automatically be pulling from the task role for these permissions, and that I shouldn't need to provide any additional config information with the task role present. Is there some additional setup I need to do in order to get the task to look at the role, rather than searching for permissions in any other location? Apologies if this is obvious, or if it has already been answered elsewhere.

Edit 1: I should also note that the operation I'm trying to execute is listObjects - it seems like this might require some different credentials requirements than get and put, but I can't figure out how this would need to look if I wanted to use the iam role as my credential.

Edit 2: Edit to add the task definition:

```
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:123456789:task-definition/projectname:321",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "projectname",
            "image": "artifactory:3829/projectname:321",
            "repositoryCredentials": {
                "credentialsParameter": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789:secret:ecs/artifactory/credentials-tuvwxyz"
            },
            "cpu": 1024,
            "memory": 2048,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "ENVIRONMENT",
                    "value": "dev"
                }
            ],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "linuxParameters": {
                "tmpfs": []
            },
            "stopTimeout": 30,
            "dockerLabels": {},
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "projectname-lg",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "projectname"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "family": "projectname",
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/projectname-task-role",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/projectname-container-task-execution-role",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 321,
    "volumes": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.private-registry-authentication.secretsmanager"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.container-ordering"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.22"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "1024",
    "memory": "2048",
    "registeredAt": "xxx",
    "registeredBy": "xxx",
    "tags": []
}
```

Edit 3: When I run `curl "169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI"` within the container, I receive the following response:

```
{
    "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/projectname-task-role",
    "AccessKeyId": "WXYZ123456789",
    "SecretAccessKey": "XXXXX",
    "Token": "XXXXX",
    "Expiration": "2023-08-28T21:28:03Z"
}
```

This makes me think that the auth from the iam role is working, and there is some other disconnect. I'm not sure where to go from here in terms of debugging. Does anyone know what may be preventing the credentials from being sufficient to perform a `listObjects` operation?

Comment: Can you add the task definition to the question? It should have taskRoleArn to specify the IAM role for your tasks

Comment: @ArpitJain Sure thing, added. The task role arn has been specified, though.

Comment: Have you set any environment variables to be used for the AWS? It will take precedence over iam role. Would you mind sharing the role policies?

Comment: Which AWS SDK are you using? And are you using the latest version of that SDK?

Comment: @ArpitJain I have a single env var set as ENVIRONMENT=dev, which is being used for other purposes within the app. The role policies are standard AWS policies, and I've noted their names in the original question - some of them are quite long, so I'm not sure if it will be practical to post them in their entirety.

Comment: @MarkB I am using version 3.190.0.

Comment: @A.S. You answered which version, but not which SDK. Which AWS SDK are you using? The PHP SDK, Python SDK, Java SDK, etc?

Comment: @MarkB I apologize, I am using the AWS SDK for Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I never found an exact answer to this, but I built around it by writing a lambda-backed API authorized by Cognito exposing each of the S3 methods I needed to use. I was then able to explicitly set my credentials in the request, and it went through.

Comment: I have very much the same problem with App Runner. How about reporting to AWS support team?